# Determine if navbar in Bootstrap is expanded or not

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I am using bootstrap and running in some problems with the collapsed navbar.
I added visual effects to some dropdown menu, but they need to be removed in the collapsed view (when the navbar is collapsed). 
I already figured out, that there is an event fired, when the view is changing to the collapsed one:

```
show.bs.collapse    This event fires immediately when the show instance method is called.
shown.bs.collapse   This event is fired when a collapse element has been made visible to the user (will wait for CSS transitions to complete).
hide.bs.collapse    This event is fired immediately when the hide method has been called.
hidden.bs.collapse  This event is fired when a collapse element has been hidden from the user (will wait for CSS transitions to complete).
```

my js is looking like this:

```
 // ADD SLIDEDOWN ANIMATION TO DROPDOWN //
$('.dropdown').mouseenter('show.bs.dropdown', function(e){
$(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).slideDown();
});

// ADD SLIDEUP ANIMATION TO DROPDOWN //
$('.dropdown').mouseleave('hide.bs.dropdown', function(e){
$(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).slideUp();
});

$(document).on('show.bs.collapse', function(e){
$('.dropdown-menu').slideDown("normal", function() {$(this).remove();});
$('.dropdown-menu').slideUp("normal", function() {$(this).remove();});
});
```

I already figured out, how to use the collapse event to remove the slideUp and slideDown effect (the effects that need to be removed). The problem is, that this removal is permernent. I need an similar event, when the website is switching to the expand mode. something like this:

```
$(document).on('show.bs.expand', function(e){
//DO FUNCTION
});
```

Is there any event fired, when the website switches from the collapsed view to the expand?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the exact event you're looking for exists but there is a work around.  You can look at the resize event to see what the size of the viewport is and work from there:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  if ($(this).width() < 768) {
    //do something
  }
});
```